# How do I get rid of the tiny chevron in the bottom right corner of the textbox control in some browsers

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, safari

```
.clASPOneP 
 {
     overflow: hidden;
     height:40px;
     width:40px;
     border-style:none;  
     border-width:0px;
     background-color:#C0C0C0;
     font-family:Courier;
     font-size:xx-large;
     padding:0px;
     text-align:center;
     vertical-align:middle;
 }
```

I do not get a chevron in IE but I do in Chrome, Firefox and Safari

Answer (score 3):

The chevron is for resizing the text area. To remove it, use:

```
.clASPOneP {
    resize: none;
}
```

[Source](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=5f9cd62207e2c7a8&hl=en)